# Print all broadcasted vsomeip messages in routing manager?

Tags: c++, vsomeip

I am new to `vSOME/IP`, and I am working on a system that all `SOME/IP` messages are broadcasted via `Ethernet`, so basically any `vSOME/IP` application (Service provider, consumer, even the routing manager) can see the messages being sent.

I tried to develop a simple application that only starts a `vsomeip` application, and lot of log messages shows up (I assume that are the broadcasted messages):

```bash
...

2022-07-21 11:19:10.949493 [info] REGISTERED_ACK(0006)
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949551 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx1:is_provider=false]
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949580 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx2:is_provider=false]
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949598 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx3:is_provider=false]
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949614 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx4:is_provider=false]
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949630 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx5:is_provider=false]
2022-07-21 11:19:10.949647 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0006): [xxxx6:is_provider=false]

...

2022-07-21 11:19:10.989091 [info] Application/Client 0009 is registering.
2022-07-21 11:19:10.989158 [info] Client [20] is connecting to [9] at /tmp/vsomeip-9
2022-07-21 11:19:10.989622 [info] REGISTERED_ACK(0009)

...

2022-07-21 11:19:11.268943 [info] Client [20] is connecting to [12] at /tmp/vsomeip-12
2022-07-21 11:19:11.269018 [info] Application/Client 001c is registering.
2022-07-21 11:19:11.269075 [info] Client [20] is connecting to [1c] at /tmp/vsomeip-1c
2022-07-21 11:19:11.269201 [info] REGISTERED_ACK(0012)
2022-07-21 11:19:11.269993 [info] REGISTERED_ACK(001c)
2022-07-21 11:19:11.270024 [info] REGISTER EVENT(0012): [xxxx1:is_provider=false]

...
```

As you can see, the application detects that multiple clients are connecting and some `REQUEST`s and `EVENT`s are happening.

My question is how to dump the messages data and access its content?
I do not need to subscribe to a specific `service ID`, because everything is **broadcasted**.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use tools like tcpdump or Wireshark?

Comment: I tried tcpdump and it only shows the hex data, I need to develop a deserializer to extract the information I need, but I want to do it from a someip application.

Comment: In Wireshark, I think you can specify how to deserialize and it will show all the values for respective fields.

Comment: Yes, I know that is possible, but the reason why I need it via C++ application, is that I want to make it exposes an API that I can call in distance to get a specific SOMEIP signal value.

Comment: You probably need to use some vsomeip API which will give you the payload of the message packet which would contain the data.

Comment: That is what I am asking if anyone knows how to extract the messages without subscribing to specific services.